# Adding class does not change height after div height is modified using .height() method

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I can toggle the height of `.box` between `0px` and `30px` by adding and removing the `.collapsed` class. This works fine.

However, I've got another function that toggles the height of `.box` between `30px` and `60px` using the `.height()` method. The problem I'm having is that if I use `.height()` to modify `.box`'s height at all, adding the `.collapsed` class no longer affects `.box`'s height. `$(.box).hasClass("collapsed")` evaluates as `true`, yet the height does not change to `0px`.

My question is, why is this happening?

**FIDDLE:** https://jsfiddle.net/x89dbbw1/4/

**HTML:**

```
<button class="toggle_collapse_button">Toggle Collapse</button>
<button class="toggle_expand_button">Toggle Expand</button>
<p id="test">Collapsed: false</p>
<div class="box"></div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.box {
    width: 160px;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: orange;
}

.collapsed {
    height: 0px;
}
```

**JS:**

```
$(".toggle_collapse_button").on("click", function() {
    if ($(".box").hasClass("collapsed")) {
        $(".box").removeClass("collapsed");
    } 
    else {
        $(".box").addClass("collapsed");
    }
    document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = "Collapsed: " + $(".box").hasClass("collapsed");
});

$(".toggle_expand_button").on("click", function() {
    if ($(".box").height() == 30) {
        $(".box").height(60);
    } 
    else if ($(".box").height() == 60) {
        $(".box").height(30);
    }
});
```

Note: It works fine if I toggle between `30px` and `60px` by adding and removing a class, but I specifically want to expand using `.height()` and collapse using a class, if possible.

Comment: `.height()` adds an inline `style` attribute to the specific element, and that takes precedence over styles from stylesheets.

Comment: You should just add a new class called `expanded` and append it (or remove it) when needed.

Comment: @Barmar I see, that makes sense. What would be the best way to get around this, if I want to continue using `.height()`? Using `.removeAttr()` before adding `.collapsed` class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use jQuery.height() it adds an inline style to the element, inline styles take precedence over all other styles aside from those with the `!important` flag.

A good read on css precedence: http://vanseodesign.com/css/css-specificity-inheritance-cascaade/

jquery docs: http://api.jquery.com/css/

Answer (score 0):

That is because you are adding the `height` inline and its override the CSS
You should do that

```
            $(".toggle_collapse_button").on("click", function() {

                $(".box").removeClass("height60");
                $(".box").removeClass("height30");
                if ($(".box").hasClass("collapsed")) {
                    $(".box").removeClass("collapsed");
                } 
                else {
                    $(".box").addClass("collapsed");
                }

                document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = "Collapsed: " + $(".box").hasClass("collapsed");
            });

            $(".toggle_expand_button").on("click", function() {

                if ($(".box").height() == 30) {
                    // $(".box").height(60);
                    $(".box").addClass('height30');

                } 
                else if ($(".box").height() == 60) {
                    $(".box").addClass('height60');
                }
            });
```

And of course the properly css style to height30 and height60

Check the example

[the Example](https://jsfiddle.net/x89dbbw1/4/)